# why the intermediate labed value should be encrypted in Garbled Circuits?

Tags: garbled-circuits

I do not know why the intermediate value (for example, W5, W6) should be encrypted??

I think the encryption (random value) only needs in the input process (e.g. w1, w2, w3, w4).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for example $w5$ is not encrypted in this diagram and I see that its value is 1 (or I see the unencrypted value 1 in the LUT for $G1$). It is the output of the AND gate $G1$ and so can only be 1 if both the input wires are 1. This would allow me to know the values of $w1$ and $w2$ that produced this input and removed the confidentiality of the inputs.